# How can i make my snake movement not delayed

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

i am making a snake game, by myself but i ran into a problem when i pressed my keys my interval pauses for a major time, i dont want it to pause i want it to continue going on

```
   const trackMovement = () => {
        let direction
        const catchError = (e) => {
            // cells that are places on the border
            if (e instanceof TypeError) {
                location.reload()
            } else {
                location.reload()
            }
        }
        let movementInterval;
        const movePlayerMinus = (num) => {
            try {
                const newIndex = randomGreenIndex - num;
                // Check if the new index is within the grid boundaries and not hitting the right wall
                // when you divide by 16 all the left cells - num of the wall have a remainder of 15
                // This checks to see if a new row has started
                if (newIndex >= 0 && newIndex % 16 === 15) {
                    location.reload()
                } else {
                    playerGreenCell.classList.remove(snakeColor);
                    randomGreenIndex = newIndex;
                    playerGreenCell = cellArray[randomGreenIndex];
                    playerGreenCell.classList.add(snakeColor);
                }
            } catch (e) {
                catchError(e);
            }
        };

        const movePlayerPositive = (num) => {
            try {
                const newIndex = randomGreenIndex + num;
                // Check if the new index is within the grid boundaries and not hitting the left wall
                // when you divide by 16 all the right cells + num of the wall have no remainder
                // this checks to see if a new row has started
                if (newIndex < cellArray.length && newIndex % 16 === 0) {
                    location.reload()
                } else {
                    playerGreenCell.classList.remove(snakeColor);
                    randomGreenIndex = newIndex;
                    playerGreenCell = cellArray[randomGreenIndex];
                    playerGreenCell.classList.add(snakeColor);
                }

            } catch (e) {
                catchError(e);
            }
        };
        document.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
            if (movementInterval) {
                clearInterval(movementInterval);
            }
            switch (e.key) {
                case "ArrowUp":
                case "w":
                case "W":
                    movementInterval = setInterval(() => movePlayerMinus(16), 200)
                    break;
                case "ArrowDown":
                case "s":
                case "S":
                    movementInterval = setInterval(() => movePlayerPositive(16), 200)
                    break;
                case "ArrowRight":
                case "d":
                case "D":
                    movementInterval = setInterval(() => movePlayerPositive(1), 200)
                    break;
                case "ArrowLeft":
                case "a":
                case "A":
                    movementInterval = setInterval(() => movePlayerMinus(1), 200)
                    break;
                default:
                    console.log("not working")
            }
        });


    };
```

https://github.com/MuhammaduBarry/Snake-Game - is my github, i am using vite, if you want to test it out you can do `npm run dev` in the terminal. thank you in advanced

When i press my keys it slows down or just stops if the interval is slow enough, i think i am doing it wrong but i just need a little guidance.

Answer (score 2):

You need to de-couple the key event from the movement, right now each key press, when it happens will restart the interval. So if you were 299 into a 300 delay, that gap becomes 599 and the UI will look jumpy.

Traditionally in games like this the rendering and movment of the character and any other sprites happen in a regular clock cycle, the game loop. Key interactions are asynchronous so pressing the direction keys just sets the next movement vector, but does not cause the movement to happen.

This way you can alter the speed of the game and keep the motion smooth. In your current logic the player can easily create race conditions by mashing keys too quickly.

1. Add a "game loop" to your app, this is the only interval that executes movement. Only a pause or end of game action should stop this timer.
2. On keypress store the movement action and increment in variables.
3. Make the "game loop" use the variable values to determine the movement for each frame.

This allows the user to rapidly change direction (or their mind) without affecting the rendering or game speed.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but i have almost no idea what you've said, Im a noob is it okay if you can show me what you mean by that. by the way i appreciate your help

Comment: @Muhammad: I'd suggest you read up on the suggestions here rather than ask Chris to write your code for you.  You'll learn a lot more that way, and next time you will be better prepared for such a task.